# Java method polymorphism when casting parameter to generic variable

Tags: java, generics, casting, polymorphism

Given the following class

```
public class Test<T extends Test.UpperClass> {

    public static class BottomClass {}
    public static class UpperClass extends BottomClass {}
    public void method(BottomClass c) {
        System.out.println("BottomClass " + c.getClass());
    }
    public void method(T c) {
        System.out.println("UpperClass " + c.getClass());
    }
    public void test() {
        method(new UpperClass());
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test<UpperClass>().method(new UpperClass()); // calls method(T)
        new Test<UpperClass>().test(); // calls method(BottomClass)
    }
}
```

The code above if executed, will print out `UpperClass class Test$UpperClass` and `BottomClass class Test$UpperClass`, which is not what I expected as `T extends UpperClass`, I would expect both will call `method(T)` as the erasure of `T` is `UpperClass`. Why `method(BottomClass)` is called instead?

Comment: You can't pass a `UpperClass` where `T` is expected. Why would the erasure matter?

Answer (score 2):

Let's simplify:

```
public class Foo<T> {
    void method(T t) {}

    void test() {
        method(new Object());  // compiler error: is T Object?
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Foo<Object>().test();
        new Foo<String>().test(); // both must compile!
    }
}
```

The above method call doesn't compile, because the instance can't know what type `T` is. The fact that `Object` and `T` have the same erasure is irrelevant at compile time. Your example is a more convoluted demonstration of the same.

Comment: Thanks. But if erasure does not matter, then in your example code, why can't you add `void method(Object t) {}`?

Comment: @user1589188 The compiler needs to make sure the methods can be distinguished at runtime, so it can't allow signatures with the same erasure. That's one of the unfortunate failings of generics in Java. But if type erasure took full effect at compile time, generics wouldn't exist at all.

Comment: Thats the reason of my question: if `method(T)` has the same signature as `method(Object)` after erasure and is not allowed, then why calling `method(new Object())` does not call `method(T)`? I know it won't compile, but I am after the logical reason behind.

Comment: @user1589188 Because the signature affects overload resolution, which also happen at compile time.

Comment: Yes you answered why having both `method(T)` and `method(Object)` is not allowed. My question is about given `method(T)` and `method(Object)` are having the same signature after erasure, then why calling `method(new Object())` does not call `method(T)`?

Comment: @user1589188 It would, if it compiled. It doesn't compile because that would violate generics.

Comment: Your simplified example doesn't compile, but mine does, thats why I have created my example to show even when it compiles, it does not call `method(T)`.

Comment: @user1589188 Your example compiles because the call resolves to a method with a different signature. That has no bearing on the fact that at compile time generic types are treated differently than their erasure.

Comment: At compile time, we already know T is UpperClass, so the real question is why it still resolves to `method(BottomClass)` but not `method(T == UpperClass)`?

Comment: @user1589188 At compile time we *do not* know what `T` is **within the instance**. Again, see my example. Is `T` an `Object` or `String`? Within `test()` it can be either.

Comment: I will answer your question, please answer mine. Your first line `new Foo<Object>().test();` I dont see an issue, as T is just replaced by Object. The second line `new Foo<String>().test();` has issue because after replacing T with String, compiler finds that will end up calling `method(String)` with a new Object(). Hence issue here.

Comment: @user1589188 It was a rhetorical question. Inside the object, `T` can be any type, therefore you can't pass a specific type in its place. The same applies to your example. Just replace `Object` with `UpperClass` and `String` with `SomeClassThatExtendsUpperClass`.

Comment: `T` cannot be changed once `Foo<Object> f;` is declared. All method calls using `f` will have `T = Object`. Same for `Foo<String> s;`, `T = String`. This is known at compile time. With this piece of information, I don't understand why the compiler would complain about `method(new Object())` when `T` is fixed to be Object after declaring `Foo<Object>`. Or in my example, why `method(T == UpperClass)` is not called when `Test<UpperClass>` is declared.

Comment: @user1589188 By your reasoning, should `method("foo");` also compile? What about `method(123);`?

Comment: This compiles: public class Test<T> {
    void method(T t) {}
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test<String>().method(new String());
    }
}

Comment: @user1589188 Just like I've been telling you: `T` is only known outside the instance.

Comment: Exactly. The instance does not know, but the compiler or us or anyone outside the instance knows, and it is not dynamic, it is static, won't change for the life time of the program. So what makes the compiler fail to see this fact?

Comment: Answer my previous question please.

Comment: I don't know where you are getting at. Both compiles here `public class Test<T> {
    void method(T t) {}
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test<String>().method("foo");
        new Test<Integer>().method(123);
    }
}`

Comment: No, in my example, where it's called from the instance.

Comment: I think I can only give up here with you. Thanks for your information but my question is still not answered. I have updated my question to make it clearer. Hope someone else can pin point the question I have.

Comment: The question *is* answered, even if you failed to understand it. But perhaps someone can explain it better. Good luck.